# convert ascii hex to integer?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I purchased an ID-20LA RFID reader. 
This is the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ID/ID-2LA,%20ID-12LA,%20ID-20LA2013-4-10.pdf).

I have compatible RFID cards that have a 10 digit unique ID printed on them.
When I scan one of these cards with A DIFFERENT reader (this reader is a USB unit with output via USB like a keyboard), I get the correct ID that is printed on the card. "0012176734"

The problem:
When I scan the SAME card with the ID-20LA RFID reader I get back "\x020300B9CD5E29/r/n\x03".
The datasheet explains that "0300B9CD5E"(DATA 10 ASCII) is the part I care about. "29" is a checksum.

So my question is how do I get "0012176734" from "0300B9CD5E"?
The datasheet details state encoding = Manchester 64bit, modulus 64. I dont know if this is relevant.

What I have tried:
Python
int('0300B9CD5E',16)
12897078622

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you skip the first byte, `Python int('00B9CD5E',16)` is `12176734`

Comment: Aziz, thank you. You have saved me a lot of headache. I don't understand what the first byte is for. But at this point I'm just happy to be able to move on. Thanks again.